# R: visualizing differences across a large number of groups

Tags: r, visualization

[I have a dataset](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/plot.csv) having the unique IDs of manufacturing units, the industrial classification of their outputs (CAT) and the number of people each unit employs (EMP). I want to graphically show that EMP varies by CAT, i.e. employment size in general varies by the kind of output a unit produces. I tried boxplots arranged by median EMP:

```
a = read.csv("/filepath/plot.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
bymedian = with(a, reorder(CAT, log(as.numeric(as.character(EMP))), median))
boxplot(log(EMP) ~ bymedian, data=a, horizontal=F, notch=T, pch=1, cex=.25, col="gray95", boxwex=.25, las=2, outline=F)
pch=1, cex=.25, col="gray95", boxwex=.25, las=2, outline=F)
```

The problem is that because of the large number of categories (400+), the plot becomes very messy. Is there a cleaner way of showing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ggplot2` you can show what you are trying to do with a `scale_x_discrete`

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
a$bymedian = with(a, reorder(CAT, log(EMP), median))
p <- ggplot(a,aes(y=log(EMP),x=bymedian))+
     geom_boxplot()

breaks <- levels(a$bymedian)[seq(1,nlevels(a$bymedian),20)]
p %+% scale_x_discrete(breaks = breaks,  labels = breaks)
```

Comment: Hi agstudy... I'm getting this error: "Error in seq.default(1, nlevels(a$bymedian), 20) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument"